# Get Microsoft Store updates available for the UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, updates

I want user to notify if the Microsoft store has updates for the app.After researching I found below code and implemented it.

```
 public static async Task<bool> IsStoreUpdatesAvailable()
    {
         try
        {
            if (context == null)
                context = StoreContext.GetDefault();

            IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates = await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
            Logs.Write.Success("Store updates are available? :" + updates.Any().ToString());
            return updates.Any();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

When I run it in my machine in debug mode or release mode it works fine.But when I try a release build in another machine it logs the following error.

> Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024500C StackTrace:    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() + 0x21
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task) +
> 0x70    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task)
>
> - 0x38    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task) + 0x17
>   at
>   com.IronOne.BoardPACWinApp.Helpers.WindowsStoreServiceHelper.d__3.MoveNext()
> - 0x105

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Can you access the Partner Center in that device? Based on the message, we could know there is a task failed in the WindowsStoreServiceHelper. It will be better if you could debug locally or remote debug on that device.

Comment: Yes Partner center can be accessed.unfortunatly I cannot recreate the issue while debuging locally.and cannot do a remote debug for that machine.

Comment: I just tested on my environment, and it works correctly. It's hard to locate the issue if you could debug locally. Do you have a third device which could test the app? And would you like to add more log to make sure in which line of code, it throws the issue?

Comment: Yes. I'll try addingmore logs

Comment: Could you test this in a third device?